# File management in C++

Tags: c++

I have a requirement for reading, updating and deleting a file. I want to write a class for this. 
For example

```
class FileManagement {
private:
    fstream myFile;

public:
    void read();
    void update();
    void delete();

};
```

My question is while updating is it possible to delete only one line in a file in C++ and should be portable, if it is possible how we can achieve this.
Other question is if above option is not possible how we can achieve the above.

In C++ how we can delete a file in portable way.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example code is not proper C++. delete is language keyword and you can not use it as member function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be asking two different questions at once, in a confusing way.

- To *delete a file*, use the [`remove`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/remove/) function, found in `stdio.h`.
- To *erase one line of a file*, you have to read the entire file and write it back out with the line removed.  There is no library routine for this.  The standard "safe" technique is to read the entire file, write it back out (with the line you don't want removed) to a *new* file in the same directory, [`fsync`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/fsync/) the new file, close it, then [`rename`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/rename/) the new file to the old name.  If you don't care about concurrent readers or the computer crashing in the middle of the operation, you can instead open the old file read/write, read its contents into memory, [`rewind`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/rewind/) the file handle, and rewrite it directly.

Answer (score 8):

Use standard C/C++ functions fopen(), fread(), fwrite(), rename() and remove() for that. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/

Answer (score 7):

I recommend [Boost Filesystem.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)

Its description reads:
"The Boost Filesystem Library provides portable facilities to query and manipulate paths, files, and directories."

Comment: boost::filesystem is a good way to manipulate file and directory paths, since it deals with character encodings in a somewhat platform-independent manner. As for actual data I/O, the C++ way is to use the iostream functions, but the C functions from stdio can give better performance.

Comment: @blue boost::filesystem is about filesystem manipulations, not actual I/O. File I/O is part of the C++ standard itself. No external library is needed to get portable file I/O in C++.

Comment: @chris that is true; nonetheless, there's a small section of the filesystem library which is a wrapper around <fstream>: <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>.

Comment: @blue These are just wrappers to accept the boost::filesystem::path type directly, instead of the char* the C++ standard implementation expects. The actual I/O is inherited from basic_fstream etc, not in boost.

Comment: @chris well you said _boost::filesystem doesn't cover reading/writing files_ . it turns out that it does, through std::fstream. All functionalities are offered from boost::filesystem to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard, and find the file operations (like `fopen()`).  Where platforms do not support posix, or diverge from the standard, you'll likely need to

```
 #ifdef NONPOSIXOS1 // really, this should be a good identifier of hte OS
   // write code to handle the special case
 #else
   // write code to handle the posix compliant case
 #endif
```

Comment: You can do that with standard C/C++ functions.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems will accept posix compliant statements.  You could always just define abstract base class and create different concrete implementations that use whatever platform specific instructions you need.  You could have one if def that instantiates the correct concrete class.

Comment: thanks but my question is how we can delete one line of a file in C++

Comment: Yes you read all of data in using a stream manipulate your data and write it back. that is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a higher-level C++ library that is object-oriented and can handle both filename manipulation and file I/O, POCO is a decent choice:

http://pocoproject.org

ACE is an older, battle-tested framework that includes lots of I/O support. It's commonly used for it's excellent CORBA support, but there's a lot in there:

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html

And, finally, there's QT. Normally known for its cross-platform UI library, QT actually includes several other useful pieces (including file management and I/O), and you don't even have to link in the UI stuff if you don't need it.

http://qt.nokia.com/

If you'd rather not bring in another framework, I would recommend rolling your own File I/O classes using boost::filesystem and either the standard iostream or stdio functions. You can use the interfaces in the above frameworks as a reference, but you will also want to familiarize yourself with modern C++ design, as demonstrated by Boost and explained in [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315).